# Disable Edit Item from the SharePoint Ribbon

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server

In my sharepoint 2013 list dispform.aspx, I have one webpart with 'save' button . Once that save button is clicked i want to disable the 'Edit Item' OOTB option from the ribbon . How can i achieve that using javascript

Comment: you can use PowerShell using CSOM  framework. That's the recommended approach.

Comment: @samolpp, PowerShell from a custom action seems overcomplicated

Comment: @RobertLindgren , I have provided the answer using js , below.  mohammed, you can try the below solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Insert Script editor webpart and on click on the button add and call    this function*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideEdit() {
        var edit = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large");
        edit.style.display = "none";
    }       
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideEdit");
</script>
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d10c9895-a9c7-4189-a312-d20664d94dfc/hide-button-in-ribbon-bar-in-dispformaspx?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 3):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function hideEdit() {
      var edit = 
      document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-
      Large");
      edit.style.display = "none";
     }       
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideEdit");
  </script>
```

Another approach :
   You can have a look at  [here](http://kamalasekar.blogspot.in/2011/05/remove-edit-item-in-sharepoint-list.html)

Comment: When copy pasting code from a source (this one I guess; https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d10c9895-a9c7-4189-a312-d20664d94dfc/hide-button-in-ribbon-bar-in-dispformaspx?forum=sharepointgeneral) you must make that very clear in your answers, to give proper credit to the author

Comment: Mohammed, I think,I have given you the answer, so you can mark my reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the edit item menu.

1. Go to settings >> edit page
2. click the drop-down >> Edit Web Part (see diagram below)
   [image: Editing web part]
3. On the list views dialog box;
   Go to toolbox type >> select No Toolbar (see diagram below)
   [image: list views dialog box]
4. Apply >> Ok to Save.